# How can I use an inductor as an EMI sensor?

Tags: inductor, emc

In the paper "Synthetic Sensors: Towards General-Purpose Sensing" by Gierad Laput, et. al, they use a 100 mH inductor as an EMI (electromagnetic interference) sensor. They have not provided much details on the board (shown below)

[image]

I was wondering what a circuit would look like which the inductor can be an ADC input to a microcontroller. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Roll-back to what you want to achieve - don't start with an under-defined product with no provenance that I can see. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to build a platform to collect sensor data for building ML models. Specifically I'd like to understand how to get EMI data from an inductor as input to a uC.

Comment: What EMI data are you looking for - there isn't a single output voltage that is indicative of prevailing EMI.

Comment: EMI data that can detect common household electrical appliances starting up - for example a microwave. In the paper they say that the EMI sensor is sampled at 500 kHz.

Comment: EMI from a microwave will be at 2.45 GHz so sampling at 500 kHz is going to be hit and miss plus, by the look of that inductor (labelled \$\color{orange}{I}\$), it won't work above a few MHz so no, you can't. Even if the inductor was good for over 2.45 GHz, you'd need extensive analogue circuits to capture the amplitude and frequency content of the signal you might receive. That is why spectrum analysers are used.

Comment: OK, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Andy-aka In figure 5 the authors clearly show some signal picked up by the inductor when a microwave oven is on. While the microwave emission itself is at 2.4GHz, the power electronics in the microwave may radiate at a variety of other frequencies. For example, the plot also shows a signal received when the microwave door is closed due to the interior light switching on or off.

Comment: @josh it's about as useful as using a microphone to detect the sound of the microwave oven's fan or plateau turning. What will it tell you that is informative and useful. "Some signal" means what?

Comment: I would suggest reading the conference paper for more information (it will do a better job than me!), it's actually quite interesting. They combine signals from several sensors to feed into an event detection system. For EMI, they take a spectrum of the signal from the inductor and use that as an input to their classifier. See my answer below, you can detect a lot of distinct appliances that emit in the 100-250kHz band. So "some signal" is an FFT/spectrogram of whatever is picked up by the inductor acting as an antenna.

Comment: A microwave might not be the best example. There may be appliances which emit a burst of broadband EMI when you power them on, without any obvious audio signal.

http://www.gierad.com/assets/supersensor/supersensor.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see one design from the Elektroscluch [0]. It seems to be as simple as connecting an inductor to ground and then feeding the "positive" end into an amplifier (and in your case an ADC). I don't see why you need two inductors here. [This](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Misc/emf.htm) circuit uses one.

Given the sampling rate of 500kHz (if you copy the paper), you might want to put in a low pass filter around 200-250kHz anyway. On the PCB in the supersensor papre it looks like there may be an RC filter just off to the right, which maybe feeds into an op-amp buffer (unity gain amp) U8. That's a guess though, since there's no schematic.

Their conference paper does cite a couple of references that may be useful, but they seem to be more related to power line monitoring, not inductive/contactless. For example:

https://ubicomplab.cs.washington.edu/publications/electrisense/
https://ubicomplab.cs.washington.edu/publications/lightwave/

Both these papers show that lots of interesting emission in the low 100s of kHz which matches with the sampling rate in the paper.

[image]

[0] https://github.com/LOM-instruments/Elektrosluch-3-plus/blob/master/hardware/elektrosluch_schematic.pdf

Another example they cite is the Syntonistor project from CMU - that seems closer, although a lot of the conditioning circuitry here doesn't seem to be on the Synthetic sensor PCB (but who knows, we only have a photo of the top side). Also it's designed to detect 60Hz, but you could tap off the signal just after the inductor.

https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/agr/projects/syntonistor/

[image]